replace multiple urls by corresponding text in R
I have a series of url links in my excel in column A and next to them in column B I have the corresponding names/titles.
For example I have in my excel
          A                    B
https://www.bbc.co.uk      BBC_news

I want to rename the link in A to hyperlink BBC_news.
I have multipl links  and names. Is there any way to do that in R?

I can offer you the following solution to the problem
library(openxlsx)

df <- read.xlsx("your_file.xlsx", colNames = FALSE)
# Create a new workbook to store the hyperlinks
new_workbook <- createWorkbook()
# Add a new sheet to the workbook
addWorksheet(new_workbook, "Hyperlinks")
# Loop through the data frame and add hyperlinks
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  url <- df[i, 1] 
  text <- df[i, 2]  
  hyperlink_formula <- paste0('HYPERLINK("', url, '", "', text, '")')
  writeFormula(new_workbook, "Hyperlinks", hyperlink_formula, startRow = i, startCol = 1)
}
saveWorkbook(new_workbook, "hyperlinked_links.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)


It worked! many thanks!!
